# How can I unzip a file to a .NET memory stream?

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

I have files (from 3rd parties) that are being FTP'd to a directory on our server. I download them and process them even 'x' minutes. Works great.

Now, some of the files are `.zip` files. Which means I can't process them. I need to unzip them first.

FTP has no concept of zip/unzipping - so I'll need to grab the zip file, unzip it, then process it.

Looking at the [MSDN zip api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), there seems to be no way i can unzip to a memory stream?

So is the only way to do this...

1. Unzip to a file (what directory? need some -very- temp location ...)
2. Read the file contents
3. Delete file.

NOTE: The contents of the file are small - say 4k <-> 1000k.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Zip compression support is built in:

```
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
// ^^^ requires a reference to System.IO.Compression.dll
static class Program
{
    const string path = ...
    static void Main()
    {
        using(var file = File.OpenRead(path))
        using(var zip = new ZipArchive(file, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
        {
            foreach(var entry in zip.Entries)
            {
                using(var stream = entry.Open())
                {
                    // do whatever we want with stream
                    // ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Normally you should avoid copying it into another stream - just use it "as is", however, if you **absolutely need it** in a `MemoryStream`, you could do:

```
using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    stream.CopyTo(ms);
    ms.Position = 0; // rewind
    // do something with ms
}
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason, why you create file stream, and then use it in ZipArchieve constructor, instead of using ZipFile.OpenRead ?

Comment: @Uriil well, firstly I'm not sure why that class even exists: all of the methods on `ZipFile` are actually about the `ZipArchive` class - to me, they should all be static members on `ZipArchive`! But more specifically, because the OP is talking about taking data from an existing source - in this case FTP. In that scenario, you can't guarantee that you have a *file*, but you can usually assume you have a *stream*. So showing how to do it *from a stream* is more re-usable and applicable to any context, not just files. But sure: you could use `ZipFile.OpenRead` here.

Comment: @Uriil also, `ZipFile` requires an extra assembly reference (System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll), just to avoid a simple `File.OpenRead` - doesn't seem worth it

Comment: Only in .net 4.5 and later. not support XP

Comment: @linquize as professionals, we would do well ourselves to **not support XP**: doing so would put our customers/clients at risk (by offering implicit approval). That OS is officially dead. The very last EOL date is about 2 weeks away. "After 8th April 2014, support and security updates for Windows XP will no longer be available."

Comment: What about Server 2003? One more year to go!

Comment: @linquize that doesn't mean we should tacitly encourage people to keep using it ;p

Comment: `entry.open()` returns a `DeflatedStream` whose `Length` and `Position` properties will throw an exception if you try to access them.  Copying to a new stream solves the problem

Comment: @JasonBaley at the cost of requiring us to pre-emptively deflate everything into memory; pros and cons

Answer (score 27):

You can use [`ZipArchiveEntry.Open`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchiveentry.open%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get a stream.

This code assumes the zip archive has one text file.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
using (ZipArchive zip = new ZipArchive(fs) )
{
    var entry = zip.Entries.First();

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(entry.Open()))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

Comment: obvious comment: this will break in nasty ways if the data isn't text, or if the data is in an unusual encoding but lacks a BOM

Comment: @Gusdor why that edit? IMO the original was preferable and actively better, but either way this doesn't seem edit-worthy

Comment: @MarcGravell i felt it made the code more explicit for readers who may not appreciate the behavior of omitted bracers.

Comment: @MarcGravell Yeah, I added the `StreamReader` just to show the simplest use case possible. Of course, if it's not text you're reading, then `StreamReader.ReadToEnd` is not what you're looking for. (I reverted Gusdor's edit).

Comment: @dcastro I said it was an obvious comment ;p It is my experience, however, that the "obvious" is often *anything but*, depending on the reader...

Comment: @MarcGravell Agreed, thanks for pointing it out ^^ I've added a comment to the code, to avoid misleading the readers.

Comment: @MarcGravell I can understand _preferable_ but I'm still struggling with _actively better_. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Gusdor easier to read, more obvious to understand (IMO), and prevents the code exploding to the right. Code readability is a feature.

Answer (score 15):

```
using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
     foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
     {
        Stream s = entry.Open();
        var sr = new StreamReader(s);
        var myStr = sr.ReadToEnd();
     }
}
```

Comment: You need a using statements for both `Stream s` and `StreamReader sr` to automatically close them.

Answer (score 10):

Looks like here is what you need:

```
using (var za = ZipFile.OpenRead(path))
{
    foreach (var entry in za.Entries)
    {
        using (var r = new StreamReader(entry.Open()))
        {
            //your code here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SharpZipLib](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/) among a variety of other libraries to achieve this.

You can use the following code example to unzip to a `MemoryStream`, [as shown on their wiki](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/Zip-Samples#anchorMemory):

```
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip;

// Compresses the supplied memory stream, naming it as zipEntryName, into a zip,
// which is returned as a memory stream or a byte array.
//
public MemoryStream CreateToMemoryStream(MemoryStream memStreamIn, string zipEntryName) {

    MemoryStream outputMemStream = new MemoryStream();
    ZipOutputStream zipStream = new ZipOutputStream(outputMemStream);

    zipStream.SetLevel(3); //0-9, 9 being the highest level of compression

    ZipEntry newEntry = new ZipEntry(zipEntryName);
    newEntry.DateTime = DateTime.Now;

    zipStream.PutNextEntry(newEntry);

    StreamUtils.Copy(memStreamIn, zipStream, new byte[4096]);
    zipStream.CloseEntry();

    zipStream.IsStreamOwner = false;    // False stops the Close also Closing the underlying stream.
    zipStream.Close();          // Must finish the ZipOutputStream before using outputMemStream.

    outputMemStream.Position = 0;
    return outputMemStream;

    // Alternative outputs:
    // ToArray is the cleaner and easiest to use correctly with the penalty of duplicating allocated memory.
    byte[] byteArrayOut = outputMemStream.ToArray();

    // GetBuffer returns a raw buffer raw and so you need to account for the true length yourself.
    byte[] byteArrayOut = outputMemStream.GetBuffer();
    long len = outputMemStream.Length;
}
```

Comment: note: you don't need external libraries - zip support is actually present multiple times in the BCL

Answer (score 0):

Ok so combining all of the above, suppose you want to in a very simple way take a zip file called 
"file.zip" and extract it to "C:\temp" folder. (Note: This example was only tested for compress text files) You may need to do some modifications for binary files.

```
        using System.IO;
        using System.IO.Compression;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Call it like this:
            Unzip("file.zip",@"C:\temp");
        }

        static void Unzip(string sourceZip, string targetPath)
        {
            using (var z = ZipFile.OpenRead(sourceZip))
            {
                foreach (var entry in z.Entries)
                {                    
                    using (var r = new StreamReader(entry.Open()))
                    {
                        string uncompressedFile = Path.Combine(targetPath, entry.Name);
                        File.WriteAllText(uncompressedFile,r.ReadToEnd());
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```