# Read and process a remote zipped xml file in C#

Tags: c#, xml, download, stream, zip

What is the correct way to read and process a remote zipped xml file in C#?

Here is what I try:

```
private Task UpdateLegalContractors(string url)
{
    url = @"https://srv-file7.gofile.io/download/k67HY4/sampleOpenData.zip";

    string res = string.Empty;

    using (var file = File.OpenRead(url))
    using (var zip = new ZipArchive(file, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
    {
        foreach (var entry in zip.Entries)
        {
            using (var stream = entry.Open())
            using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    switch (reader.NodeType)
                    {
                        case XmlNodeType.Element:
                            res += reader.Name;
                            break;
                        case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
                            res += "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"windows - 1251\"?>";
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    var stop = 0;

    return null;
}
```

The solution was suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604941/how-can-i-unzip-a-file-to-a-net-memory-stream) question.

For me the solution gives an error once the `using (var file = File.OpenRead(url))` line is reached. The error says the following:

> {"The given path's format is not supported."}

[image]

What should I change for the solution to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is here: `https://srv-file7.gofile.io/download/k67HY4/sampleOpenData.zip`. 
`File` class works only with local files. First you must download this file to local storage and then open it. 
Eg using solution from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43165954/5481787).

Direct in memory solution:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(wc.DownloadData("URL")))
{
    using (var zip = new ZipArchive(stream, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I am very grateful for your time and attention. But that is not what I am looking for. I do not want to store the file on disk, I want to process it in memory. Are there any other ways except using the `File` class?

Comment: File calss cannot read from https. You cannot save temp file and delete it after processing?

Comment: In the scope of this question I am not considering to preserve the file on disk.

Comment: @hellouworld I completed my answer with memory processing. Written from the head so it may need to be fixed.